# Bicycle Frame: anodized Aluminium?

Tags: frames

I need help with identify what materials is this frame

[image]

[image]
[image]

I need to know if this is indeed aluminium? (weight 1.2 kg for 15 inch frame hybrid, is not ferromagnetic). 
If it is, why would it have a few green/white rust, especially at the weldings/joints?

What is the material that has yellow/bronze color outside the frame? Is it a primer? Or anodized?

I would really appreciate your help and knowledge on this matter. I would really want to paint it, but I have no idea which primer I need for this frame (aluminium or anodized...)

Disclaimer:From other question/answer (I did have a look) I guess it is aluminium, but then the rust and the color does not match Aluminium characteristics and therefore, I would like to ask.

Comment: Can you include the pics in the post? They aren't loading for me, but sometimes you get white stuff when you TIG weld aluminum wrong.

Comment: Yeah, the photos don't appear.

Comment: Looks like aluminium (could be titanium) with a outer layer of some alloy - Was thinking the green looks copper as does the frame colour, so outer is possibly an aluminium or titanium alloy. What is the value of the frame?

Comment: Just added pictures

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knowing what bicycle frame material I have](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/18378/knowing-what-bicycle-frame-material-i-have)

Comment: I did read it, the question here is not only about the frame materials, but to know whether it is Anodized Aluminium, or some strange metal alloy, so that I could buy a correct primer to paint it

Comment: Ok. I'd say ano, indicated by the coating through the BB. Painted frames are usually masked before painting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At that weight it is 99% Aluminum. This is also backed up by the sizing of the tubes, as Aluminum has a much lower density. At the sizing and thickness of the tubing for it to be Ti/Steel it would be a considerable amount heavier.

The uniformity and consistency of the yellow/bronze would lead me to think that this is most likely anodized.

Comment: Anodized Al. Just clean it as paint will not stick well to anodized surfaces.

Comment: Yeah, the color looks to be a stain added during the anodizing process.

Comment: I think so, but then it has some little rusting all over it... and it baffles me because I always believe anodized aluminium is the best rust-resistant material.

Comment: @NhânLê it may be corrosion, not rust.  Salt can corrode aluminum.

Comment: @NhânLê - "Rust" is (by most definitions) an oxide of iron, has a red/brown color, and is only possible with iron-containing alloys.  I'm not seeing anything that looks like rust in the pictures.  Corrosion can occur with most metals (anodizing is actually a form of controlled corrosion), but all I see of that (aside from the anodizing proper) is some "blotchiness" on the anodized surface, which is fairly normal, plus the speckling near the bottom of the seat tube, which is also reasonably normal.

Comment: So, if anyone could recommend whether I sand the anodized part off, or should I use a Self-etching primer for metal?